# Annotate interface function that must call super

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations

I'm creating interface and some function in it has a body.
It's required, that class that implements this interface must call super in overriding function before executing other code.
How can I do this?

```
interface Watcher {
    fun funWithoutBody()

    fun startWatching() {
        //do some important stuff which must be called
    }
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I've accidentally found, what I was looking for. It's a `@CallSuper` annotation available in `androidx.annotation` package. [Docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html#call-super)

> Use the @CallSuper annotation to validate that an overriding method
> calls the super implementation of the method. The following example
> annotates the onCreate() method to ensure that any overriding method
> implementations call super.onCreate():

```
@CallSuper
protected fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
}
```

Comment: Issue with this approach is that if you have multi module project and you need this feature withing the module which is not an Android module, you will not be able to use this annotation.

Answer (score 4):

Android Studio / IntelliJ IDEA does this sort of thing in some cases but it isn't done through annotations but through [code inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/code-inspection.html).

e.g. `MissingSuperCall` is an [Android Lint Check](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks) for which IntelliJ IDEA supports ([Integration with Android Lint tool in IntelliJ IDEA 11.1 | IntelliJ IDEA Blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/02/integration-with-android-lint-tool-in-intellij-idea-111/)).

You can create your own custom inspection if you are using Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA: [IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2 Help :: Creating Custom Inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/creating-custom-inspections.html).

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

You could just make `startWatching` abstract and call it in another function. E.g.:

```
interface Watcher {
    fun funWithoutBody()

    fun userDefinedStartWatching()

    fun startWatching() {
        //insert code you'd normally want to be called when using super()
        userDefinedStartWatching()
    }
}
```

Comment: But I want to be warned by IDE. Like when you aren't calling super.onDestroy() in android Activity

Comment: I wanna know, how it's working. Actually code is written only by me, so it's not necessary, I don't need a workaround

Comment: I think that might be a feature of the IDE, but not the code, so I'm not sure if that's actually possible when writing pure Kotlin code.

Comment: maybe it's a Java annotation? Gonna look at source code

Comment: You could of course throw an Exception when it's not called.

Comment: I don't think it's an Annotation, I believe it's just a simple boolean flag that will throw an Exception when it's not set and the IDE does the rest.